# java.net.UnknownHostException and java.net.SocketException: Too many open files

Tags: java, linux, servlets

I am running a web application on Tomcat. My application make connection to other web services to fulfill request from client. Sometime i get java.net.UnknownHostException while opening URL connection and then after sometimes I start getting java.net.SocketException: Too many open files. And my server stops accepting connection further. Please guide.

```
String  response;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
BufferedReader rd = null;
InputStream in = null;
try
{
    // Send data
    String urlStr = URL;
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();
    //   System.out.println("content length 1" +  contentLength);
    if (contentLength <= 0)
    {
        InputStream in1 = (conn).getErrorStream();
        if (in1 != null)
        {
            in1.close();
        }
        conn.getInputStream().close();
        in = null;
        conn.disconnect();
        conn = null;
        return null;
    }
    in = conn.getInputStream();
    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200)
    {
        InputStream in1 = (conn).getErrorStream();
        if (in1 != null)
        {
            in1.close();
        }
        conn.getInputStream().close();
        in = null;
        conn.disconnect();
        conn = null;
        in.close();
        in = null;
        return null;
    }
    // Get the response
    rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
    {
        stringBuffer.append(line);
    }
    response = stringBuffer.toString();
    System.out.println("full ads response = " + response);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //   ex.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    try
    {
        if (conn != null)
        {
            InputStream in1 = (conn).getErrorStream();
            if (in1 != null)
            {
                in1.close();
            }
            conn.getInputStream().close();
            in = null;
            conn.disconnect();
            conn = null;
        }
        if (rd != null)
        {
            rd.close();
            rd = null;
        }
        if (in != null)
        {
            in.close();
            in = null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
return null;
```

Answer (score 2):

`UnknownHostException` just means the URL you used refers to a non-existent hostname, or possibly that the hostname's DNS record or system was in transition at that instant.

The socket leak may be caused by your excessive cleanup code below, see comments.

When you suppress all exceptions you don't have a hope in Hades of finding out what's going wrong. So that's the first thing to fix. Never ignore exceptions. Log them. Print their stack traces. Do something.

However your code has numerous other problems as well:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
BufferedReader rd = null;
InputStream in = null;
try
{
    // Send data
    String urlStr = URL;
```

This variable is redundant. Just use `URL` below.

```
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

OK so far.

```
    int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();
    //   System.out.println("content length 1" +  contentLength);
    if (contentLength <= 0)
```

It's very unusual to check for zero content length. Is this a proxy for checking for errors? I would simply remove this test.

```
    {
        InputStream in1 = (conn).getErrorStream();
        if (in1 != null)
        {
            in1.close();
        }
        conn.getInputStream().close();
        in = null;
        conn.disconnect();
        conn = null;
        return null;
    }
```

All the above is redundant. You already have it in the finally block. Remove it.

```
    in = conn.getInputStream();
    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200)
```

Now that is how to check for errors. However you must call `getResponseCode()` *before* you call `getInputStream(),` otherwise the latter may throw `FileNotFoundException` when you might be more interested in the response code being 404.

```
    {
        InputStream in1 = (conn).getErrorStream();
        if (in1 != null)
        {
            in1.close();
        }
        conn.getInputStream().close();
        in = null;
        conn.disconnect();
        conn = null;
        in.close();
        in = null;
        return null;
    }
```

Again, all the above is redundant. You already have it in the finally block. Remove it.

```
    // Get the response
    rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;
```

Initialization of `line` is redundant. The variable is assigned in the next line. Remove it.

```
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
    {
        stringBuffer.append(line);
    }
    response = stringBuffer.toString();
    System.out.println("full ads response = " + response);
}
catch (Exception ex)
```

You should only catch `IOException` here.

```
{
    //   ex.printStackTrace();
```

**Never** ignore an exception.

```
}
finally
{
    try
    {
        if (conn != null)
        {
            InputStream in1 = (conn).getErrorStream();
            if (in1 != null)
            {
                in1.close();
            }
```

You don't need to get or close the error stream. Remove all this.

```
            conn.getInputStream().close();
            in = null;
```

Setting this variable to null is pointless. It's a local variable so it's about to fall out of scope anyway.

```
            conn.disconnect();
            conn = null;
```

Ditto.

```
        }
        if (rd != null)
        {
            rd.close();
            rd = null;
        }
```

You've already closed the input stream. This is redundant. Remove this block.

```
        if (in != null)
        {
            in.close();
            in = null;
        }
```

You've already closed the input stream of the connection. This is all redundant. Remove it.

```
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
```

Again you should only be catching `IOException` here, and you shouldn't be ignoring the error. Personally I would have the method throw `IOException` and not have any catch blocks at all. Returning null isn't very useful to the caller. He's generally better off knowing exactly what went wrong so he can make a useful decision as to what to do about it.

```
}
return null;
```

Comment: Hi EJP, Thanks for Such a detail. I really appreciate the effort.

Comment: I made this mess in my desparate effor to solve this bug quicky after reading different solution for similar problems. (I know this is a lame excuse:) )I will definitely clean it up. But the bug was there when it was clean up. Regarding enabling print stack, I comment it recently just to make my log file smaller else it just make size of stdout.log huge.

Comment: @YasirPerwez If you're getting lots of exceptions the idea is to fix the problem, not just ignore it.

Comment: @EJP. You are right. I am just trying to figure out how to solve. I will do code clean up and update the thread

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across this issue when attempting to make lots of connections to an unreachable URL. The connection would fail with UnknownHostException, but eventually fail with java.net.SocketException: Too many open files.

The issue is, an underlying native socket handle was created by HttpURLConnection. It appears that this handle isn't released until after the object is garbage collected. In my case, there wasn't enough memory being used to trigger a garbage collection. If the GC never runs, the native handles aren't released.

My solution was to periodically call System.gc() when getting the UnknownHostExceptions. I know that seems like a kludge but it worked, the underlying native handles were released and the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing your linux server open files limit to fix `java.net.SocketException: Too many open files`. The limit of max files is stored in this file in linux:

```
/proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

to check the open files at a current time, you can use:

```
lsof
```

to check the no. of open files, use:

```
lsof | wc -l
```

also, in addition to conn.disconnect(), close your connection conn.close(). Make sure that you close inputreader as well. All such close should be in finally block, so that connection is also closed in case of any exception.

Comment: Hello Ankit. I have already set to maximum that is why it takes some to reach that limit. My server git 5000 client request per minute and every request open on URL connection on server to fetch some data from other web service.

Comment: @YasirPerwez: Please note teh other recommendation that i have given, make sure that you have closed the connection and inputstream after your work is done.

Comment: I will do it surely. Cleanup my code and try it. Will update this thead about the outcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on windows or linux ? Check this article, hope it helps : http://edmund.haselwanter.com/en/blog/2009/03/13/tomcat-too-many-open-files/

Comment: Hello Martin, I am using Linux and I have already increase the limit to maximum. But it seems after java.net.UnknownHostException it leaks the socket and release it till next GC. I found this on stack flow only but I missed that link. I am running Java 1.7, Tomcat 7 on linux.